# Rollover image in a div?

Tags: html, css, image, rollover

I have a custom twitter share button that is in the bottom right of my page. Its an image inside a div that is meant to rollover, but it wont rollover. Is it even possible to add rollover images inside a div?
so is there a workaround that will make the image rollover?

HTML:

```
<div id="twitter"><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('twitter','','Images/twitterrollover_06.png',1)"><img src="Images/twitter_06.png" width="46" height="51" ></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#twitter {
font-family: "Bebas Neue";
color: #000;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
right: 40px;
bottom: -12px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Not descriptive enough! consider adding some detail and also add the JS code.

Comment: @AmanuelNega ive updated it with more details I hope that helps. I dont have any JS for this. Basically my question is how do i add an image that rollovers inside a div? Please dont leave my negative ratings, im really new to this

Comment: If you're just doing a simple image rollover do it in CSS.

Comment: What is this then if not js? ***onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('twitter','','Images/twitterrollover_06.png',1)"***

Comment: @AmanuelNega ive no idea to be honest, i just added a rollever image through dreamweaver and it wrote that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a simple image rollover don't use JS for this use CSS.

```
a.twitter {
   display: block;
   cursor: default;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background: url('images/twitter.png') top left;
}

a.twitter:hover {
   background-position: center left;
}

a.twitter:active {
   background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Mark it up in HTML like so...

```
<div class="twitter">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks alot. I just had to change them from classes to id's and tweek the positioning

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript.

```
<div class="twitter"><img src="1.png"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter")[0];//i only have one element with that tag so...
    //if you are going to put more you can loop through them
    prepareRollOver(t);//call the function to prepare the rollover
    function prepareRollOver(target){
       target.onmouseover = function (){
            img = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];//only one img expected, so take the first of the array
            img.src="src1.png"
       }
       target.onmouseout = function (){
            img = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];//only one img expected, so take the first of the array
            img.src="src2.png"
       }
    }
</script>
```

You can also do this with css like this

```
.twitter{
    background:url("1.png");
}
.twitter:hover{
    background:url("10.png");
}
```

But remove the img tag inside the div, you don't need it if you are going to use css
Change src1.png and src2.png to match your file names.